# Larger Font Size moves right in Right Aligned Text

Tags: html, css

I'm getting strange behavior when I change the font size on right aligned text. When I lower the font size, the text shifts left. More specifically, the right side of the right most character is farther left in a smaller font along with the rest of the characters.

HTML

```
<dl class="date-term">
<dt>24 Sep 2012</dt>
<dd>Lots of thinking and reading about writing this weekend, but no doing.</dd>
</dl>
```

CSS

```
p , dd
{
font-size: 1.125em;
line-height: 1.375em;
margin: 1.375em 0 1.375em 0;
color: inherit;
}
dl.date-term dt
{
float: left;
width: 5.8em;
margin-top: 0.250em;
text-align: right;
font-size: 0.8em;   /* de-emphasize */
color: #7e8b8c;     /* Make it more subdued */
}
dl.date-term dd
{
margin-left: 6.0em; /* .5em greater then width of dt above */
}
```

.2em is 2 or 3 px
My goal is to get the dt and dd closer together. The page in question can be seen [here:](http://www.zetcho.com)
If I reduce the width of the dt, it will wrap even with a smaller font size. I've tried it in Safari and Firefox on OS X.

Thanks for any help,
Curt

Comment: you mean `dt` and `dd` closer together ? in your question.

Comment: Thanks for catching the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the dt and dt closer together just reduce the `margin-left` of `dl.date-term dd` on master.css line no: 388

```
dl.date-term dd {
margin-left: 5em;
}
```

Comment: This worked even though it didn't make sense at first. I made the dd left margin less than the width of the dt. You would think they would overlap. Then I remembered that when specifying widths, margins, etc. using ems, the actual distance is relative to the font size. So a 6em width with a font-size of 1em is greater than a 6em width with a font size of 0.8em in pixels. I wouldn't have this problem if I used px, but it would be more fragile.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the line-height seems to solve the issue for me.

It may be worth looking into the shorthand / other options for font configuration:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/UAbUu/

It may also be worth looking into using relative values instead of margin-top etc.